tweepy v2 getting follower list
I'm trying to read the follower list using Tweepy v2.
import tweepy

# Your credentials

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

The above code is returning correct client information which I can verify with:
# Get your own user ID 
me = client.get_me()
my_id = me.data.id

However, I am not able to get the follower list, I tried following multiple approaches from documentation:
# Get followers
followers = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_followers, my_id, max_results=1000):
    followers.extend(response.data)


I get 401.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unauthorized                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-2fa8b522e9f3> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Get followers
      2 followers = []
----> 3 for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_followers, my_id, max_results=1000):
      4     followers.extend(response.data)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tweepy/client.py in request(self, method, route, params, json, user_auth)
     96                 raise BadRequest(response)
     97             if response.status_code == 401:
---> 98                 raise Unauthorized(response)
     99             if response.status_code == 403:
    100                 raise Forbidden(response)

Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Unauthorized

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_followers

Getting a list of followers is not available in Free, Basic or Pro access tiers.

yeah, it seems only enterprise plan can access that.
